# Measure returning the last value that is not 0 or blank?

Tags: powerbi, calculation, measure

I need to create a measure that returns the last value that was not 0 or blank, regardless of the dates that are selected.
I have a fact table where each row represents the monthly rental rate for units (1 row for each day and each unit). In the fact we have flag columns which show whether the unit is occupied this month or not. If it is not occupied then we have rental rate 0.
I need to have a table that shows the currently unoccupied units and the last rental rate paid for them.
I tried a SWITCH statement that gives me the previous year rate, if it is 0, then we take the rental rate 2 years back, if 2 years back 0 then -3 years etc. But I think this is a very inefficient way to solve this.
Do you have any suggestions?
Thanks!

Edit:
[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdeXX.png)

Comment: it is always better to post the sample data and make the explanation over the column names... and also desired output with this sample data... this way, you will have faster suggestions...

Comment: Hi, thank you for this comment. I have added a sample data in the post.